# While doing element-wise operations in NumPy, what's the best way to add a conditional statement?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a list of positive integers and I want to repeatedly subtract the smallest element from all elements, but only if the element isn't an instance of the minimum. For example, in one iteration

`a = np.array([3, 5, 9, 3, 3])` becomes `[3, 2, 6, 3, 3]` and ultimately `[1,1,1,1,1]`.

That is, no entry is ever reduced to 0. I'm suspicious there may exist an easy way to modify `a - min(a)` such that `a[0]`, `a[3]`, and `a[4]` don't become 0, but I don't know.

I know this can be accomplished with a list comprehension:

```
while len(set(arr)) > 1:

arr = [a - min(arr) if a > min(arr) else a for a in arr]
```

The arrays may be very large though, so with time efficiency in mind I'm hoping NumPy has a convenient way of doing this. I'm quite new to Python, so correction/information in all capacities is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the end result will be an array full of the GCD of the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled using the 3-clause variant of the `where` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([3, 5, 9, 3, 3])
>>> m = a.min()
>>> np.where(a != m, a - m, m)
array([3, 2, 6, 3, 3])
```

And wrap that in the while loop.

Instead of using `set`, you could also use `numpy.unique`:

```
while len(np.unique(a)) > 1:
    m = a.min()
    a = np.where(a != m, a - m, m)
```

But you should time both variations (`set` versus `unique`, list comprehension versus `where`) separately to see what works fastest for larger arrays.

Another variant is to compare the maximum and minimum: perhaps `a.max()` can be calculated faster than `np.unique`:

```
while True:
    m = a.min()
    if m == a.max():
        break
    a = np.where(a != m, a - m, m)
```